# rules condition to check whether user has flagged another

Tags: rules, flags

Hi I have two user roles, client and consultant. Currently a client is able to flag a consultant as their selected consultant.

Now here is where im stuck. I am looking to use rules to display a message to clients whom have not flagged a consultant yet. How would i go about setting up this condition within a rule?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to work something out although I dont entire understand why its working. I created a data comparison condition and set the DATA TO COMPARE to "account:flag-consultant-flag-flagged" and DATA VALUE is set to "account:flag-consultant-flag-user".

Here was my logic although I thought it would do the exact opposite. I figured that if i compared all the flagged consultants with the consultants flagged by the current user, there should be a match and so the condition would be true. Weirdly though the rule is firing for users that didnt select a consultant so it turns out it did the exact opposite. If anyone is able to give some clarity, it would be much appreciated.